# What is the meaning of ImagePullBackOff status on a Kubernetes pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to run my first kubernetes pod locally.
I've run the following command (from [here](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker/)):

```
export ARCH=amd64
docker run -d \
    --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
    --volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
    --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:rw \
    --volume=/var/lib/kubelet/:/var/lib/kubelet:rw \
    --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw \
    --net=host \
    --pid=host \
    --privileged \
    gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube-${ARCH}:${K8S_VERSION} \
    /hyperkube kubelet \
        --containerized \
        --hostname-override=127.0.0.1 \
        --api-servers=http://localhost:8080 \
        --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests \
        --cluster-dns=10.0.0.10 \
        --cluster-domain=cluster.local \
        --allow-privileged --v=2
```

Then, I've trying to run the following:

```
kubectl create -f ./run-aii.yaml
```

**run-aii.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: aii
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: aii
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: aii
        image: aii
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5144
        env:
        - name: KAFKA_IP
          value: kafka
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /root/script
          name: scripts-data
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /home/aii/core
          name: core-aii
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /home/aii/genome
          name: genome-aii
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /home/aii/main
          name: main-aii
          readOnly: true
      - name: kafka
        image: kafkazoo
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /root/script
          name: scripts-data
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /root/config
          name: config-data
          readOnly: true
      - name: ws
        image: ws
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
      volumes:
      - name: scripts-data
        hostPath:
          path: /home/aii/general/infra/script
      - name: config-data
        hostPath:
          path: /home/aii/general/infra/config
      - name: core-aii
        hostPath: 
          path: /home/aii/general/core
      - name: genome-aii
        hostPath: 
          path: /home/aii/general/genome
      - name: main-aii
        hostPath: 
          path: /home/aii/general/main
```

Now, when I run: `kubectl get pods`
I'm getting:

```
NAME                    READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
aii-806125049-18ocr     0/3       ImagePullBackOff   0          52m
aii-806125049-6oi8o     0/3       ImagePullBackOff   0          52m
aii-pod                 0/3       ImagePullBackOff   0          23h
k8s-etcd-127.0.0.1      1/1       Running            0          2d
k8s-master-127.0.0.1    4/4       Running            0          2d
k8s-proxy-127.0.0.1     1/1       Running            0          2d
nginx-198147104-9kajo   1/1       Running            0          2d
```

BTW: `docker images` return:

```
REPOSITORY                                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ws                                         latest              fa7c5f6ef83a        7 days ago          706.8 MB
kafkazoo                                   latest              84c687b0bd74        9 days ago          697.7 MB
aii                                        latest              bd12c4acbbaf        9 days ago          1.421 GB
node                                       4.4                 1a93433cee73        11 days ago         647 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube-amd64   v1.2.4              3c4f38def75b        11 days ago         316.7 MB
nginx                                      latest              3edcc5de5a79        2 weeks ago         182.7 MB
docker_kafka                               latest              e1d954a6a827        5 weeks ago         697.7 MB
spotify/kafka                              latest              30d3cef1fe8e        12 weeks ago        421.6 MB
wurstmeister/zookeeper                     latest              dc00f1198a44        3 months ago        468.7 MB
centos                                     latest              61b442687d68        4 months ago        196.6 MB
centos                                     centos7.2.1511      38ea04e19303        5 months ago        194.6 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/etcd              2.2.1               a6cd91debed1        6 months ago        28.19 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/pause             2.0                 2b58359142b0        7 months ago        350.2 kB
sequenceiq/hadoop-docker                   latest              5c3cc170c6bc        10 months ago       1.766 GB
```

why do I get the ImagePullBackOff ??

Comment: Is `aii` a private image that you've built?

Comment: Yes, aii, kafkazoo and ws are mine

Answer (score 55):

By default Kubernetes looks in the public Docker registry to find images. If your image doesn't exist there it won't be able to pull it.

You can run a local Kubernetes registry with the [registry cluster addon](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/registry).

Then tag your images with `localhost:5000`:

```
docker tag aii localhost:5000/dev/aii
```

Push the image to the Kubernetes registry:

```
docker push localhost:5000/dev/aii
```

And change run-aii.yaml to use the `localhost:5000/dev/aii` image instead of `aii`. Now Kubernetes should be able to pull the image.

Alternatively, you can run a private Docker registry through one of the providers that offers this (AWS ECR, GCR, etc.), but if this is for local development it will be quicker and easier to get setup with a local Kubernetes Docker registry.

Comment: I've tried https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/ (looks easier) - but how/where in kubernetes can I set my registry location?

Comment: Can I use docker registry (locally)? should I configure it somewhere in kubernetes? Am I start it correctly (with the long command above)?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use Docker registry locally.

Comment: The GitHub link returns 404 Not Found

Answer (score 22):

One issue that may cause an `ImagePullBackOff` especially if you are pulling from a private registry is if the pod is not configured with the `imagePullSecret` of the private registry.

An authentication error may cause an `imagePullBackOff`.

Comment: how can one check for that log?

Comment: `kubectl logs  pod/pod-name -n <namespace>` if you have more than 1 contain in the pod `kubectl logs  pod/pod-name -c container -n <namespace>`

Comment: One other way is to `kubectl get events -n <namespace>`

Answer (score 15):

You can specify also `imagePullPolicy: Never` in the container's spec:

```
containers:
- name: nginx
  imagePullPolicy: Never
  image: custom-nginx
  ports:
  - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: What’s the effect on that?

Comment: Yeah, there seems to be an important piece of information missing -- how does Kubernetes get the image to begin with then?

Comment: I am getting this error with this spec: ErrImageNeverPull

Comment: This would only work if the image is already present locally. Then it won't try to pull again - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#image-pull-policy

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem what caused  it was that I already had created a pod from the docker image via the .yml file, however I mistyped the name, i.e test-app:1.0.1 when I needed test-app:1.0.2 in my .yml file. So I did `kubectl delete pods --all` to remove the faulty pod then redid the `kubectl create -f name_of_file.yml` which solved my problem.

Answer (score 11):

I too had this problem, when I checked I image that I was pulling from a private registry was removed
If we describe pod it will show pulling event and the image it's trying to pull

```
kubectl describe pod <POD_NAME>

Events:
 Type     Reason   Age                  From              Message
 ----     ------   ----                 ----              -------
 Normal   Pulling  18h (x35 over 20h)   kubelet, gsk-kub  Pulling image "registeryName:tag"
 Normal   BackOff  11m (x822 over 20h)  kubelet, gsk-kub  Back-off pulling image "registeryName:tag"
 Warning  Failed   91s (x858 over 20h)  kubelet, gsk-kub  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Comment: This helps tp give me more details of the Error: Image Pull Back Off

Answer (score 11):

The issue arises when the image is not present on the cluster and k8s engine is going to pull the respective registry.
k8s Engine enables 3 types of **ImagePullPolicy** mentioned :

1. **Always** : It always pull the image in container irrespective of changes in the image
2. **Never** : It will never pull the new image on the container
3. **IfNotPresent** : It will pull the new image in cluster if the image is not present.

Best Practices : It is always recommended to tag the new image in both docker file as well as k8s deployment file. So That it can pull the new image in container.

Answer (score 4):

Debugging step:
`kubectl get pod [name] -o yaml`

Run this command to get the YAML configuration of the pod ([Get YAML for deployed Kubernetes services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43941772/get-yaml-for-deployed-kubernetes-services)). In my case, it was under this section:

state:
waiting:
message: 'rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get
https://repository:9999/v2/abc/location/image/manifests/tag:
unauthorized: BAD_CREDENTIAL'
reason: ErrImagePull

Answer (score 3):

Despite all the other great answers none helped me until I found a comment that pointed out this [Updating images](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images):

> The default pull policy is `IfNotPresent` which causes the kubelet to skip pulling an image if it already exists.

That's exactly what I wanted, but didn't seem to work.

Reading further said the following:

> If you would like to always force a pull, you can do one of the following:
>
> - omit the `imagePullPolicy` and use `:latest` as the tag for the image to use.

When I replaced `latest` with a version (that I had pushed to minikube's Docker daemon), it worked fine.

```
$ kubectl create deployment presto-coordinator \
    --image=warsaw-data-meetup/presto-coordinator:beta0
deployment.apps/presto-coordinator created

$ kubectl get deployments
NAME                 READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
presto-coordinator   1/1     1            1           3s
```

Find the pod of the deployment (using `kubectl get pods`) and use `kubectl describe pod` to find out more on the pod.

Answer (score 3):

My issue got resolved upon adding the appropriate tag to the image I wanted to pull from the DockerHub.

Previously:

```
containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: alex/my-app-image
```

Corrected Version:

```
containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: alex/my-app-image:1.1
```

The image has only one version, which was 1.1. Since I skipped that initially, it has thrown an error.

After correctly mentioning the version, it worked fine!!

Answer (score 2):

ImagepullBackoff mesns you have not passed secret in your yaml or secret is wrong and might be you image name is wrong.

If you pulling image from private registry you have to provide image pull secret then it will able to pull image.

you also need to creat secrete before you  deploy the pod. you can use below command to create secrete.

```
 kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=artifacts.exmple.int --docker-username=<username> --docker-password=<password> -n <namespace>
```

you can pass secret in yaml like below.

```
 imagePullSecrets:
 - name: regcred
```

Answer (score 2):

for me I was logged in to a docker private registry and tried to pull the public image, so tried `docker logout` solved the issue for me.

so you can also validate the images you are using if public or private, then try `docker login` or `docker logout` upon that.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem when using minikube over hyperv with 2048GB memory.
I found that in HyperV manager the Memory Demand was higher than allocated.

So I stopped minikube and assigned somewhere between 4096-6144GB. It worked fine after that, all pods running!

I don't know if this can nail down the issue in every case. But just have a look at the memory and disk allocated to the minikube.

Answer (score 1):

I had face same issue.

imagePullBackOff means it is not able to pull docker image from registry or smoking issue with your registry.

the solution would be as below.

```
1.  Check you image registry name.
2.  check image pull secrets.
3.  check image is present with same tag or name.
4.  check you registry is working.
```

Answer (score 1):

**To handle this error, Just have to create Kubernetes secrets and use it in manifest.yaml file**

If it is private repository then it is mandatory to use user secrets

To generate secrets -

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry docker-secrets --docker-server=https://index.docker.io/v1/ --docker-username=ExamplaName --docker-password=ExamplePassword --docker-email=example@gmail.com
```

for **--docker-server**, use https://index.docker.io/v1/

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
   name: test-pod
spec:
   containers:
   - name: test
     image: ExampleUsername/test:tagname
     ports:
     - containerPort: 3015
   imagePullSecrets:
   - name: docker-secrets
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I tried to create a `replicationcontroller`. The issue was, I wrongly spelt the nginx image name in template definition.

**Note**: This error occurs when kubernetes is unable to pull the specified image from the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

```
[mayur@mayur_cloudtest ~]$ kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-598b589c46-zcr5d   0/1     ImagePullBackOff    0          6m21s
```

Later I found that the docker on which the pod is created is using a private registry for images and Nginx was not present in it.

I have changed the docker registry to default and reloaded the daemon.
Post that issue got resolved.

```
[mayur@mayur_cloudtest ~]$ kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-598b589c46-7cbjf   1/1     Running   0          33s
[mayur@mayur_cloudtest ~]$
[mayur@mayur_cloudtest ~]$
[mayur@mayur_cloudtest ~]$ kubectl exec -it nginx-598b589c46-7cbjf -- /bin/bash
root@nginx-598b589c46-7cbjf:/# ls
bin   dev                  docker-entrypoint.sh  home  lib64  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  docker-entrypoint.d  etc                   lib   media  opt  root  sbin  sys  usr
root@nginx-598b589c46-7cbjf:/#
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case, Kubernetes was not able to communicate to my private registry running on localhost:5000 after update to MacOS Monterey. It was running fine previously. The reason was Apple Airplay now listen to port 5000.
In order to resolve this issue, I disabled Apple Airplay receiver.

Go To System preference > Sharing > Disable checkbox for Airplay receiver.

Source Link: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332