# Get YAML for deployed Kubernetes services?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy my app to *Kubernetes* running in *Google Container
Engine*.

The app can be found at: https://github.com/Industrial/docker-znc.

The *Dockerfile* is built into an image on *Google Container Registry*.

I have deployed the app in *Kubernetes* via the + button. I don't have the YAML
for this.

I have inserted a *Secret* in *Kubernetes* for the PEM file required by the app.

1. How do I get the YAML for the *Deployment*, *Service* and *Pod* created by
    Kubernetes by filling in the form?
2. How do I get the *Secret* into my *Pod* for usage?

Comment: You can follow this lab session on how to export yaml of deployed k8s services- https://youtu.be/Wc9T4tdcsr0

Answer (score 381):

To get the yaml for a deployment (service, pod, secret, etc):

```
kubectl get deploy deploymentname -o yaml
```

Comment: any idea how to do it for the full cluster (all deployments)? The idea being, of course, to create mirror environments with the exact same services.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic, List exports are not supported so far and don't seem to be coming soon. You will probably need a script to list all ressources then cycle through those ressources to build your list. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24855#issuecomment-329889844

Comment: As of Kubernetes 1.14, `--export` is deprecated; see [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.14.md#deprecations). You can use `get -o yaml` without `--export`, although that includes information about the current object state, as well as the declarative configuration needed to (re)configure the object.

Comment: Still need to remove some current state from the yaml generated by "-o yaml", for example, ```spec.clusterIP``` and ```metadata.resourceVersion``` in service.

Comment: --export option does not work now. Need alternative approach

Comment: `kubectl get deploy deploymentname -o yaml > mydepl.yaml`

Comment: This answer is deprecated and should be edited, as `--export` is now an error.

Comment: this answer was useful while watching this very useful tutorial on k8s https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X48VuDVv0do&t=2087s&ab_channel=TechWorldwithNana

Comment: Note: you can also use `-o json` to get JSON format

Comment: Any idea what file exactly this command reads from?

Answer (score 44):

> How do I get the YAML for the Deployment, Service and Pod created by
>   Kubernetes by filling in the form?

```
kubectl get deployment,service,pod yourapp -o yaml --export
```

Answering @Sinaesthetic question:

> any idea how to do it for the full cluster (all deployments)?

```
kubectl get deploy --all-namespaces -o yaml --export
```

The problem with this method is that *export* doesn't include the namespace. So if you want to export many resources at the same time, I recommend doing it per namespace:

```
kubectl get deploy,sts,svc,configmap,secret -n default -o yaml --export > default.yaml
```

Unfortunately kubernetes [still doesn't support](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/527) a true *get all* command, so you need to list manually the type of resources you want to export. You can get a list of resource types with

```
kubectl api-resources
```

Comment: `kubectl get $(kubectl api-resources | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n +2 | tr '\n' ',' | sed s/,\$//) -o yaml > manifest.yaml`

Answer (score 26):

The same issue is discussed [at kubernetes GitHub issues page](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24873) and the user "alahijani" made a bash script that exports all yaml and writes them to single files and folders.

Since this question ranks well on Google and since I found that solution very good, I represent it here.

*Bash script exporting yaml to sub-folders:*

```
for n in $(kubectl get -o=name pvc,configmap,serviceaccount,secret,ingress,service,deployment,statefulset,hpa,job,cronjob)
do
    mkdir -p $(dirname $n)
    kubectl get $n -o > $n.yaml
done
```

Another user "acondrat" made a script that do not use directories, which makes it easy to make a `kubectl apply -f` later.

*Bash script exporting yaml to current folder:*

```
for n in $(kubectl get -o=name pvc,configmap,ingress,service,secret,deployment,statefulset,hpa,job,cronjob | grep -v 'secret/default-token')
do
    kubectl get $n -o yaml > $(dirname $n)_$(basename $n).yaml
done
```

The last script does not include service account.

Comment: --export is deprecated, right?

Comment: `error: unknown flag: --export`, suggest replacing `kubectl get -o=yaml --export $n > $n.yaml` with `kubectl get $n -o yaml > $n.yaml`

Answer (score 22):

Now that `--export` is deprecated, to get the output from your resources in the 'original' format (just cleaned up, without any information about the current object state (unnecessary metadata in this circumstance)) you can do the following using `yq` `v4.x`:

```
kubectl get <resource> -n <namespace> <resource-name> -o yaml \
  | yq eval 'del(.metadata.resourceVersion, .metadata.uid, .metadata.annotations, .metadata.creationTimestamp, .metadata.selfLink, .metadata.managedFields)' -
```

Comment: I like this one, just one note yq is not usually on OS

Comment: Before you install krew to install this on Windows, kubectl-neat "does not offer installation" for Windows

Comment: @markbaldy Your comment addresses [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68984976/1529709), right?

Comment: This is nice! For the record, the yq utiliy lives at https://github.com/mikefarah/yq

Answer (score 15):

**Syntax for downloading yaml's from kubernetes**

```
kubectl get [resource type] -n [namespace] [resource Name] -o yaml > [New file name]
```

**Create yaml file from running pod:**

1. `kubectl get po -n nginx nginx-deployment-755cfc7dcf-5s7j8 -o yaml > podDetail.yaml`

**Create replicaset yaml file from running pod:**

2. `kubectl get rs -n nginx -o yaml > latestReplicaSet.yaml`

**Create deployement yaml file from running pod:**

3. `kubectl get deploy -n nginx -o yaml > latestDeployement.yaml`

Answer (score 12):

If you need to get 'clean' export, removing the annotations added by Kubernetes, there's an opensource project that does that by piping the output of `kubectl get` - https://github.com/itaysk/kubectl-neat.

It removes the timestamp metadata, etc.

```
kubectl get pod mypod -o yaml | kubectl neat

kubectl get pod mypod -oyaml | kubectl neat -o json
```

Answer (score 11):

Also its possible to use the [view-last-applied](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands) command e.g.

```
kubectl apply view-last-applied services --all > services.yaml
```

which will return all the manifests applied to create services. Also you can specify a certain k8 resource by services/resource-name label.

Comment: This seems like the cleanest answer.

Comment: I tested it on `Endpoints`. This only gives the values that were applied manually. Even if that object is completely changed by the system (endpoints are most of the times created by services) you will still get the old value which was manually set.

Answer (score 8):

All services

```
kubectl get service --all-namespaces -o yaml  > all-service.yaml
```

All deployments

```
kubectl get deploy --all-namespaces -o yaml  > all-deployment.yaml
```

Answer (score 8):

To get YAML for current running  deployment on kubernetes, you can run this command:

```
kubectl get deployment <deployment_name> -o yaml
```

To generate YAML for deployment you can run the imperative command.

```
kubectl create deployment <deployment_name>--image=<image_name> -o yaml
```

To generate and export the deployment you can run the imperative command.

```
 kubectl create deployment <deployment_name>--image=<image_name> --dry-run=client -o yaml > example.yaml
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this command to get yaml format of your service

`kubectl get service servicename -n <namespace> -o yaml`

You can put it in some file also

`kubectl get service servicename -n <namespace> -o yaml > service.yaml`

Answer (score 7):

The following code will extract all your K8s definitions at once and place them on individual folders below the current folder.

```sh
for OBJ in $(kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name)
do
   for DEF in $(kubectl get --show-kind --ignore-not-found $OBJ -o name)
   do
      mkdir -p $(dirname $DEF)
      kubectl get $DEF -o yaml \
      | yq eval 'del(.metadata.resourceVersion, .metadata.uid, .metadata.annotations, .metadata.creationTimestamp, .metadata.selfLink, .metadata.managedFields)' - > $DEF.yaml 
   done
done
```

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28401429)

Answer (score 6):

1. You can store output of deployed kubernetes service by using below command -

   kubectl get svc  -n  -o yaml > svc-output.yaml

For deployments -

```
kubectl get deploy <deployment-name> -n <your-namespace> -o yaml > deploy-output.yaml
```

For Pod -

```
kubectl get pod <pod-name> -n <your-namespace> -o yaml > pod-output.yaml
```

2. You can get your secret details using below command -

   kubectl get secret  -n  -o yaml
   In order to use update your deployment file by using below command -

   kubectl edit deploy  -n 
   Under your pod template add below -

- this will go under pod containers section to mount secret volume to container

  ```
    volumeMounts:
    - name: foo
      mountPath: "/etc/foo"
      readOnly: true
  ```
- this will go inside your pod template section in deployment

  ```
  volumes:
  - name: foo
    secret:
      secretName: mysecret
  ```

Answer (score 5):

for the 2nd question regarding the secret, this is from the k8s documentation. see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets for more info.

1. Create a secret or use an existing one. Multiple pods can reference the same secret.
2. Modify your Pod definition to add a volume under spec.volumes[]. Name the volume anything, and have a spec.volumes[].secret.secretName field equal to the name of the secret object.
3. Add a spec.containers[].volumeMounts[] to each container that needs the secret. Specify spec.containers[].volumeMounts[].readOnly = true and spec.containers[].volumeMounts[].mountPath to an unused directory name where you would like the secrets to appear.
4. Modify your image and/or command line so that the program looks for files in that directory. Each key in the secret data map becomes the filename under mountPath.

I have used this and it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

- Like mentioned above "--export" is one option to get the manifest corresponding to the kubeernetes objects
- But "--export" is considered to be buggy and there is a proposal to deprecate it
- Currently the better option is to do "-o yaml" or "-o json" and remove the unnecessary fields
- The main difference is "--export" is expected to remove the cluster specific settings (e.g. cluster service IP of a k8s service). But it is found to be inconsistent in this regard

Answer (score 4):

We can get the contents associated with any kind from a Kubernetes cluster through the command line if you have the read access.

```
kubectl get <kind> <kindname> -n <namespace> -o <yaml or json>
```

For example, if you want to export a deployment from a namespace follow the below command -

```
kubectl get deploy mydeploy -n mynamespace -o yaml > mydeploy.yaml

kubectl get deploy mydeploy -n mynamespace -o json > mydeploy.json
```

Answer (score 4):

To get all yaml file deployments backup (not a specific deployment):

```
kubectl get deployments -n <namespace> -o yaml > deployments.yaml
```

for getting all yaml file services backup (not a specific deployment):

```
kubectl get services -n <namespace> -o yaml > services.yaml
```

enjoy it.

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl -n <namespace> get <resource type> <resource Name> -o yaml
```

With the command above, any resource defined in Kubernetes can be exported in `YAML` format.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to view and edit the file use:

`kubectl edit service servicename`

Answer (score 1):

You can try use [kube-dump](https://woozymasta.github.io/kube-dump/) bash script

With this utility, you can save Kubernetes cluster resources as a pure yaml manifest without unnecessary metadata.

[image]

- [GitHub repository](https://github.com/WoozyMasta/kube-dump)
- [Review of the utility in blog page](https://woozymasta.medium.com/how-to-back-up-kubernetes-cluster-resources-as-yaml-files-33564504b4ed)

Answer (score 1):

We can get yaml for deployed resources using below command.

```
kubectl get <resource name> -o yaml

                OR
kubectl get <resource name> <name of pod> -o yaml
```

example:-

```
  kubectl get deploy Nginx -o yaml
```

above commands  will give you yaml output.

if you want to store the output into any file you can use below command.

```
kubectl get pod nginx -o yaml > Nginx-pod.yaml
```

above command will redirect you output to Nginx-pod.yaml in your courrent directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below command :-

`kubectl get deploy <NameofYourDeployment> -o yaml`

In case you want to save it to a file use below

`kubectl get deploy <NameofYourDeployment> -o yaml > deploy.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can get the yaml files of the resources using this command

   `kubectl -n <namespace> get <resource type> <resource Name> -o yaml`
2. To get the secret into your pod,

use something like this

```
env
- valueFrom
    secretKeyRef:
      name: secret_name
      key: key_name
```

or

```
envFrom
- secretRef:
    name: secret_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Is only minor difference from @Janos Lenart's answer!

`kubectl get deploy deploymentname -o yaml > outputFile.yaml` will do

Answer (score -1):

I know it is too old to answer, but hopefully, someone will find it helpful.

We can try below command to fetch a kind export from all namespace -

```
kubectl get <kind> --all-namespaces --export -o yaml
```