# ImagePullBackOff on helm install on minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am running the following command

```
helm upgrade --install --wait sample-db bitnami/postgresql \
     --namespace database \
     --set auth.postgresPassword=password \
     --set auth.replicationPassword=repl_password \
     --set auth.database=sample_app \
     --set architecture=replication
```

on a `minikube` instance started as follows:

```
minikube start --vm-driver=hyperkit --kubernetes-version=1.22.1
```

`minikube` version is `minikube v1.23.0 on Darwin 11.6.1`

However pods fail:

```
Failed to pull image "docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:14.2.0-debian-10-r22": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.64.1:53: read udp 192.168.64.5:58443->192.168.64.1:53: read: connection refused
```

Comment: Refer to this [link](https://www.tutorialworks.com/kubernetes-imagepullbackoff/) for more causes and troubleshooting. Also check the [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302776/what-is-the-meaning-of-imagepullbackoff-status-on-a-kubernetes-pod) case with a similar issue.

Comment: Has your issue resolved? Does the above links helped?